# How to make the json data to convert in the pdf format using typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, pdf, jspdf

i have json data, i need to convert that to pdf format onclick of PDF button in UI.
I want the pdf format to appear in this template format. I have done few things but i am not getting how to bind the response to the pdf function.
Here i want 2 scenarios to get matched, here in the `"actualExpenses"` array i need to display all the values in block and have `"expenses"` array in each of 
"actualExpenses" array of objects and i want this `"expenses"` array of objects to come just above the "actualExpenses" particular objects.

DEMO: [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jdzg6s?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Template:

[image]

TS:

```
captureScreen() {
    this.displayTable = true;
    let grossItems = [];
    grossItems.push(this.grossItems);
    console.log(grossItems)
    var doc = new jsPDF();
        var col = [
          "Actual",
          "Based Amount",
          "Fixed %",
          "80% GU ",
          "85% GU",
          "90% GU",
          "95% GU",
          "100% GU"
        ];
        var col1 = [
          "Estimate",
           "Based Amount",
          "Fixed %",
          "80% GU ",
          "85% GU",
          "90% GU",
          "95% GU",
          "100% GU"
        ];
        var rows = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < grossItems[0].actualExpenses.length; i++) {
          var temp = [];
          for (var key in grossItems[0].actualExpenses[i]) {
            temp.push(grossItems.actualExpenses[i][key]);
          }
          rows.push(temp);
          console.log(temp, "temp");
        }
        doc.setFont("Times New Roman");
        doc.setFontSize(10);
        doc.text(20, 10, grossItems.propertyName);
        doc.text(20, 20, "Property Name Goes Here");
        doc.text(20, 30, "Budgeted Year:");
        doc.setTextColor(0, 0, 0);
        doc.text(20, 40, "Actual Occupancy:");
        doc.autoTable(col, rows, {
          theme: "plain",
          startY: 45,
          margin: {
            top: 45
          },
          drawHeaderRow: (head, data) => {
            data.doc.setLineWidth(0.7);
            data.doc.setDrawColor(0, 0, 0);
            data.doc.line(
              data.cursor.x,
              data.cursor.y,
              data.cursor.x + data.table.width,
              data.cursor.y
            );
            data.doc.line(
              data.cursor.x,
              data.cursor.y + head.height,
              data.cursor.x + data.table.width,
              data.cursor.y + head.height
            );
          }
        });
        doc.autoTable(col1, rows, {
          theme: "plain",
          startY: 100,
          margin: {
            top: 100
          },

          drawHeaderRow: (head, data) => {
            data.doc.setLineWidth(0.7);
            data.doc.setDrawColor(0, 0, 0);

            data.doc.line(
              data.cursor.x,
              data.cursor.y,
              data.cursor.x + data.table.width,
              data.cursor.y
            );

            data.doc.line(
              data.cursor.x,
              data.cursor.y + head.height,
              data.cursor.x + data.table.width,
              data.cursor.y + head.height
            );
          }
        });
        document
          .getElementById("convertToPdf")
          .setAttribute("src", doc.output("datauri"));
 }
```

Can anyone help me out to bind values and make my pdf appear as in template, i hope layout is fine, now the only issue is to bind values to the template.

Answer (score 0):

your `captureScreen()` should look like.

```
captureScreen() {
this.displayTable = true;
let grossItems = [];
grossItems.push(this.grossItems);
console.log(grossItems)
var doc = new jsPDF();
    var col = [
      "Actual",
      "Based Amount",
      "Fixed %",
      "80% GU ",
      "85% GU",
      "90% GU",
      "95% GU",
      "100% GU"
    ];
    var col1 = [
      "Estimate",
       "Based Amount",
      "Fixed %",
      "80% GU ",
      "85% GU",
      "90% GU",
      "95% GU",
      "100% GU"
    ];
    var rows = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < grossItems[0].actualExpenses.length; i++) {
      var temp = [];
      temp.push(grossItems[0].actualExpenses[i].category); // ADDED
      for (var key in grossItems[0].actualExpenses[i]) {
        temp.push(grossItems[0].actualExpenses[i].baseAmount); // CHANGED HERE
      }
      rows.push(temp);
      console.log(temp, "temp");
    }
    doc.setFont("Times New Roman");
    doc.setFontSize(10);
    doc.text(20, 10, grossItems[0].propertyName);
    doc.text(20, 20, "Property Name Goes Here");
    doc.text(20, 30, "Budgeted Year:");
    //  doc.text(50, 30, grossItems.owner.company);
    doc.setTextColor(0, 0, 0);
    doc.text(20, 40, "Actual Occupancy:"); 
    //  doc.text(55, 40, grossItems.owner.actual);
    doc.autoTable(col, rows, {
      theme: "plain",
      startY: 45,
      margin: {
        top: 45
      },
      drawHeaderRow: (head, data) => {
        data.doc.setLineWidth(0.7);
        data.doc.setDrawColor(0, 0, 0); // draw black lines
        // Write the line at the top of header
        data.doc.line(
          data.cursor.x,
          data.cursor.y,
          data.cursor.x + data.table.width,
          data.cursor.y
        );
        // Write the line at the bottom of header
        data.doc.line(
          data.cursor.x,
          data.cursor.y + head.height,
          data.cursor.x + data.table.width,
          data.cursor.y + head.height
        );
      }
    });
    doc.autoTable(col1, rows, {
      theme: "plain",
      startY: 100,
      margin: {
        top: 100
      },

      drawHeaderRow: (head, data) => {
        data.doc.setLineWidth(0.7);
        data.doc.setDrawColor(0, 0, 0); // draw black lines
        // Write the line at the top of header
        data.doc.line(
          data.cursor.x,
          data.cursor.y,
          data.cursor.x + data.table.width,
          data.cursor.y
        );
        // Write the line at the bottom of header
        data.doc.line(
          data.cursor.x,
          data.cursor.y + head.height,
          data.cursor.x + data.table.width,
          data.cursor.y + head.height
        );
      }
    });
    document
      .getElementById("convertToPdf")
      .setAttribute("src", doc.output("datauri"));
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for response, but as it is array of objects, i cannot expect grossItems[0] will only be there, it may have array of objects as well so it must dynamically take the values

Comment: so you meant to say that ` grossItems` can either be an object or an array??

Comment: ya, right now it is having only one object, in future it may have multiple objects

Comment: So, how i need is in the table, we get columns, then it displays the actualTotal object values initally, then the actual expenses have set of categories and those categories have its own expenses, so expenses names will be in row1 and row2 for example and last category name will display, so it must continue fr all

Comment: All I can say is try to know the `typeof`(keyword) compare to the object and then act accordingly. I'm sorry a bit caught up.

Comment: ya il try, if possible pls do help me out

Comment: can you update the question with both the possibility?

Comment: Is my question clear? or shall i elaborate it and even more clearly shall i post?

Comment: I would want to see what exactly you're getting for `grossItems`

Comment: i had put console in ngOninit with grossItems, that is what exactly i am getting from response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192307/discussion-between-bhrungarajni-and-abhishek-ekaanth).